# How Can I Integrate mobileCore Stickeez Ad?

Tags: android

I explored mobileCore a month ago and decided to use today. But I couldnt integrate.

My Code for İntegrate Stickeez Ad Type:

```
MobileCore.init(MainActivity.this, "4U5PUKTA688XO2HBFI8O2SPYVVJ47",
                    MobileCore.LOG_TYPE.PRODUCTION,MobileCore.AD_UNITS.INTERSTITIAL, MobileCore.AD_UNITS.STICKEEZ);

    MobileCore.showStickee(MainActivity.this, MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER.APP_START);
```

I dont know why showStickee but it isnt wrong. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you're trying to show the ad unit before it is ready. We recommend to use the Ad Unit Event Listener to confirm that the ad unit is ready before calling `showStickee()`, or at least to not call it together with `MobileCore.Init()`.

Also, if you're using the latest version (v2.0), note that we've added a new `loadAdUnit()` method that requires to manually fetch the ads before displaying.

Here's an example using Android SDK v2.0:

**First, In the onCreate() method of your main activity, Init the SDK:**

```
MobileCore.init(MainActivity.this, *YOUR_DEVELOPER_HASH_HERE*,
                    MobileCore.LOG_TYPE.PRODUCTION,MobileCore.AD_UNITS.INTERSTITIAL, MobileCore.AD_UNITS.STICKEEZ);
```

**Now here's an example code that loads the ad unit after Init has finished and then displays the ad upon receiving `AD_UNIT_READY` event:**

```
    MobileCore.setAdUnitEventListener(new AdUnitEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdUnitEvent(MobileCore.AD_UNITS adUnit, EVENT_TYPE eventType,
                                  MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER... trigger) {
            if (adUnit == MobileCore.AD_UNITS.STICKEEZ) {
                if (eventType == EVENT_TYPE.AD_UNIT_INIT_SUCCEEDED) {
                    MobileCore.loadAdUnit(MobileCore.AD_UNITS.STICKEEZ, MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER.APP_START);
                }
                else if (eventType == AdUnitEventListener.EVENT_TYPE.AD_UNIT_READY) {
                    for (MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER myTrigger : trigger) {
                        if (myTrigger.equals(MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER.APP_START)) {
                            MobileCore.showStickee(MainActivity.this,
                                    MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER.APP_START);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Feel free to contact us at support@mobilecore.com with any question.

Comment: still it doesnt working MobileCore.init(MainActivity.this, "4U5PUKTA688XO2HBFI8O2SPYVVJ47",
     MobileCore.LOG_TYPE.PRODUCTION, MobileCore.AD_UNITS.STICKEEZ);
  
  MobileCore.loadAdUnit(MobileCore.AD_UNITS.STICKEEZ,
         MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER.APP_START);
  MobileCore.showStickee(this, MobileCore.AD_UNIT_TRIGGER.APP_START);